# Method always returns true

Tags: android, string, boolean

I have a method that checks for achievements and I am trying to get it to work properly. It  takes a String and converts it to a long and then checks against a String value in the database ( Which is converted to long )

here is the code:

```
public boolean checkAchievements(String timeString) {   
    long timeInt = Long.parseLong(timeString);
    boolean newAchievement = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT millis FROM records ORDER BY CAST(millis as SIGNED) DESC", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long topTime = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0));
    cursor.close();

    if (timeInt > topTime) {
        db.rawQuery("update achievements set completed='yes' where name='Beat top record'", null);
        newAchievement = true;
    }

    db.close();

    return newAchievement;
}
```

Ihe `timeString` is the current time in milliseconds grabbed from the calendar and converted into a string from a long. I have no idea why this function keeps returning true especially when i know for a fact that timeInt is not greater than topTime.

also, even though this function is returning `true`, that update query isn't even running because i checked the database and the completed value is still "no" where name="Beat top record".

Comment: When you say you "know for a fact that timeInt is not greater than topTime" is that because you examined the values in the debugger? On an off-topic: you might consider adding "LIMIT 1" to your SELECT query.

Comment: well ted, my UPDATE query isn't working either, even though the function is returning true....

Comment: Are you sure the device/emulator is running the code you think it is?

Comment: @TedHopp asked a valid question, which you ignored (about "knowing for a fact") and made a suggestion about adding to your SQL. You might edit your question to provide that info.

Comment: Let me clarify my earlier comment: the code you posted _cannot_ return `true` unless `timeInt > topTime`. Therefore your assumption (not "fact") that `timeInt <= topTime` must be wrong (or, as @Dave suggested, you aren't running the code you posted). I was suggesting that you test your assumption with the debugger. That the db is not updated (even if the `update` query is executed) might be due to other factors; it is not proof that the body of the `if` is not executing.

Comment: @scarhand would you please update your question with the topTime's value in the question. I believe that will clear all the doubts :)

Comment: nevermind im stupid as hell. the topTime is a long which contains a value that is the difference between 2 millisecond times. theTime is a long which contains the current time, so, of course, its always larger.

Comment: In that case @scarhand, my answer suits your question most, kindly accept it so that it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is returning `true` which is correct as per the condition. Let me explain you in details.

as you said in question your timeString variable contains the current milliseconds which is a long value of milliseconds since 1st Jan 1900. Your time value in database is the old one than the current time ( i am assuming that, as you haven't given its value in question ). So suppose you have top time is of yesterday ( i.e. 31st May 2012 ). Now when you compare this value with today's current time, your method is going to return `true` which is correct itself.

for checking the false value i would like to suggest you to store some future time like greater than the today's date ( i.e. 1st June 2012 ) and the execute the method, it will surely return `false` value.

Comment: You're assuming facts not in detail. There's no indication that `timeString` refers to any specific value, we have no idea what the timestamp is in the database, and you didn't address the fact that the `update` isn't working. So I guess it's 'returning true which is correct' if all of the things you assume are true actually are, but we have no way of knowing.

Comment: agree with you, lets ask scarhand to put the topTime's value in the question @KenWhite

Comment: @KenWhite - OP did post that "`timeString` is the current time in milliseconds grabbed from the calendar and converted into a string from a long". This answer seems like the most likely explanation, but only OP can say for sure. Good catch, by the way, Lucifer.

Comment: @KenWhite, please read the OP's comment, my assumption was right, Its obvious that today you record one record with timestamp and when you compare this record tomorrow with current timestamp, the value of timestamp will be large. Generally we never store the future timestamp unless it is case of licencing.